# parse.com local javascript file does not work but the url file works fine

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome app and using the parse.com for data storage.

For a chrome app the java script file need to be locally saved. I have copied the java script from the parse web java script and made a local file.

My program does not work with the local file and work perfect with the web java script.

```
    <!-- Parse local file-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse-1.5.0.min.js">
</script>

    <!-- Parse url file-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The API script accesses their API server:

[image: code]

- **Chrome extension**: to allow the access add a [content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) rule for the url in `manifest.json`:

  ```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://api.parse.com; object-src 'self'"
  ```
- **Chrome apps** are much more strict and you'll have to put the page with that API script into a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox) (or in an invisible/nullsized iframe - [info](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#sandboxing)) to be able to specify CSP and communicate with the iframe [via messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#postMessage):

  ```
  {
    ...
    "sandbox": {
      "pages": ["parse-sandbox.html"],
      "content_security_policy": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src https://api.parse.com"
    },
    ...
  }
  ```

  parse-sandbox.html:

  ```html
  <html><head><script src="js/parse-1.5.0.min.js"></script></head><body></body></html>
  ```

Comment: I see what your talking about and i made the changes. Now i get this error when loading.   "content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app."   any ideas

Comment: You've tagged the question as `google-chrome-extension` whereas the correct tag is `google-chrome-app`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. that code gives me an error.  I see an error in the syntax. too many square brackets and not enough curly brackets. i have tried this code also.  'code' {
  ...
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["parse-sandbox.html"]
    "content_security_policy": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src https://api.parse.com"
  },
  ...
}'code'

Comment: @Morgan, thanks, I've fixed the typo with the bracket, but note that this is an example which you are supposed to adapt (preferably after studying the provided documentation links), please don't ask me to do it for you.

Comment: I have worked with it some more and i am still not able to get it going. i have added a comma after the "pages": ["parse-sandbox.html"],     this stopped some errors loading. The js code is still not processing like it did as a regular webpage.

Comment: Well, thanks for finding another typo, as for `not processing like it did` I can't comment on that, could be anything. Debug it.